# RDLC Report Viewer Control - How to open images in another window/tab

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, rdlc, report-viewer2010

I have images in the database (SQlServer 2008 R2) in a varbinary column. My report is developed in ASP.net 3.5 in Visual Studio 2010. On my report in a table, I use an Image, set the MIME type to image/jpeg, image source as Database & the image is displayed correctly in the report. Everything works!! Now my issue is that, I would like to add a hyperlink to that image so that when the user clicks on the image it opens in another window/tab in its original format. This will help the user to get a closer look at the image.
I tried to add Hyperlink - Go to URL - Expression

="http://localhost:49170/MtkMobileDeposit_FailedTransaction/Account/ReportByUserName.aspx?BackImageOriginal=" & Fields!BackImageOriginal.Value

But I cannot get it to display only the image. Instead it displays the entire report in a new tab. How do I first get the URL for the images to work ? Please help.

Thanks,
sdd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use a httphandler to process your request.

Create an ImageHandler.ashx that will take in the record id. Then you can get the image's byte array and out put it to the screen.

Your new URL will look like

"/ImageHandler.ashx?Record_ID=" & Fields!RecordId.Value

```
public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler
{

    public int Record_ID
    {
        get { return Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["Record_ID"]); }

    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        // get image from database into a byte array
        Component.ImageController objImageController = new Component.ImageController();
        Component.ImageInfo objImageInfo = objImageController.getImage(Record_ID);
        byte[] byteArray = objImageInfo.photo;

        // output it to the screen
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(byteArray);

        context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();

    }



    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code.  I created an httpHandler. Added the Url link inside my report to point to the ashx file - ="http://localhost:49170/MtkMobileDeposit_FailedTransaction/Account/ReportByUserName.aspx/ImageHandler.ashx?ID=" & Fields!ID.Value        When I run the report a new window is opened with the correct url, but no image is displayed. Is there some setting which I am missing in the config file??

Comment: Are you sure you have the right URL, looks like you have "../ReportByUserName.aspx/ImageHandler.ashx?ID"  but it shouldn't have the "ReportByUserName.aspx" in the url.